# Impressions per Post on Instagram Graph API

Tags: rest, api, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I've been trying to get the impressions per post with the Instagram Graph API Explorer, but haven't been able to.

The following code works perfectly to get each post with it's caption, like_count, media_type, comments_count and timestamp:

```
{instagram-id}/media?fields=caption,like_count,media_type,comments_count,timestamp&limit=100
```

But somehow, I haven't been able to add the impressions to that list. 
The code to get the impressions for one single post works fine and it is:

```
{post-id}/insights/impressions/lifetime
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
insights?metric=impressions,reach
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/insights